# JSON/Datatable: Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new on flutter but I work a lot for learning all I need for my projects.

**I have a JSON sent by a server using HTTP:**

```
[{"equipe1":"PSG","equipe2":"DIJON","type_prono":"1N2"},

{"equipe1":"MONACO","equipe2":"REIMS","type_prono":"1N2"},

{"equipe1":"TOULOUSE","equipe2":"RENNES","type_prono":"1N2"},`{"equipe1":"MONTPELLIER","equipe2":"STRASBOURG","type_prono":"1N2"},{"equipe1":"AMIENS","equipe2":"METZ","type_prono":"1N2"},{"equipe1":"BREST","equipe2":"ANGERS","type_prono":"1N2"},{"equipe1":"LORIENT","equipe2":"CHAMBLY","type_prono":"1N2"}]`
```

And I try to set it to a datatable widget but it seems complicated to do.

**Now here is my entire code:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

// Create a Form widget.
class Affiche_grille extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Affiche_grille_State createState() {
    return Affiche_grille_State();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.

class Affiche_grille_State extends State<Affiche_grille> {
  @override
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Grille_display() async {
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'http://www.axis-medias.fr/game_app/display_grid.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_grille': 1};

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    var match = json.decode(response.body);

    return match;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    var valjson = Grille_display();
    var ListEquipe=EquipeList(breed: [valjson]);
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            DataTable(
              columnSpacing: 20,
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Eq 1"),
                  numeric: false,
                  tooltip: "",
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Eq 2"),
                  numeric: false,
                  tooltip: "",
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Type pro"),
                  numeric: false,
                  tooltip: "",
                ),
              ],
              rows: ListEquipe.breed.map((Match_detail) => DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(Match_detail.equipe1.toString()),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(Match_detail.equipe2.toString()),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(Match_detail.typeProno.toString()),
                    ),
                  ]),
              ).toList(),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}

class Match_detail {
  String equipe1;
  String equipe2;
  String typeProno;

  Match_detail({this.equipe1, this.equipe2, this.typeProno});

  Match_detail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    equipe1 = json['equipe1'];
    equipe2 = json['equipe2'];
    typeProno = json['type_prono'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['equipe1'] = this.equipe1;
    data['equipe2'] = this.equipe2;
    data['type_prono'] = this.typeProno;
    return data;
  }
}

class EquipeList {
  List <Match_detail> breed;

  EquipeList({this.breed});

  factory EquipeList.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    return EquipeList(
        breed: json
            .map((e) => Match_detail.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

**i have now changed with last information but now no error from flutter/dart but errors when simulate on android i have an error**

type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Match_detail'

Comment: its dart (flutter being the framework).
problem is, that you call map on an object of type EquipeList - which you defined yourself. but you have not defined a method map in your class. you probably want to call map on the List within the object. probably `rows: EquipeList.breeds.map ... `

Comment: Error is in this line `rows: EquipeList.map((equipe_detail) => DataRow(`. Because `EqupeList` does not contains `map` named constructor. I think you should use `breeds` property of `EquipeList` instance. Method `map` is available for `List/Map`.
P.S. You should increase your code writing skill, man.

Comment: It is flutter/dart code

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not access instance members from class's itself.

```dart
class EquipeList {
  List<Match_detail> breeds;
  EquipeList({this.breeds});
  ...
}
```

`breeds` is instance member (does not have `static` modifier).

Instead of `EquipeList.breeds` you need to construct a instance then access to its members.

```
var equipeList = EquipeList(breeds: [ ... ]);

...
rows: equipeList.breeds.map( ... ).toList()
```

## Static member / Instance member

```dart
class Demo {
  // Static member
  static int var1;

  // Instance member
  int var2;
}

class AnotherClass {
  void main() {
    // Accessing static member via class
    Demo.var1 = 15;   // works

    // Accessing instance member via instance
    var inst = Demo();
    inst.var2 = 24;   // works

    // Accessing static member via instance
    inst.var1 = 45;   // fails

    // Accessing instance member via class
    Demo.var2 = 64;   // fails
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but : var equipeList = EquipeList(breed: [...]); What do you insert between []. What is the … ?

Comment: @axis-medias i don't know. It's based on your own propouse. Which data would you like to show as list, put it there

Comment: and now it doesn't work i have no errors with my code, it displays the table title of column but Nothing in the detail, no rows :(

Comment: I can not help more than that. Because your problem probably in bloc (business logic) side.

Comment: the problem is i have put Nothing between [ ] and as you said i need display the data i need so equipe1 and equipe2 but i Don't see how i can display that between the [ ]

Comment: Flutter is very complicated for doing Something which is normally easy to do :( I have tried that : var ListEquipe = EquipeList(breed: [listmatch]); listmatch is the json but now i have another error pff error: The element type 'Future' can't be assigned to the list type 'Match_detail'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at [flutter_app] lib\grid.dart:40)

Comment: @axis-medias you need to learn some stuff (async programming, oop, ...) about app developing.

Comment: between the [ ] of your example, i need to put the json source is it good ???

Comment: if i change the function async and delete future i have not this error but an another… type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Match_detail'

Comment: @axis-medias you need to fix too much things. Since this website is for asking question, not fixing code I suggest you to ask your question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have done it and people says me i need post here lol if code doesn't work….

Comment: @MisirJafarov **DO NOT TELL PEOPLE WITH BROKEN CODE TO POST ON [codereview.se].**  Broken code is strictly off-topic there -- only working code is eligible for review.  If a question on Stackoverflow is Too Broad or Needs More Focus, it can be closed here with these justifications.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm so sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Build Widget with [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Match_detail>>(
        future: Grille_display(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

          return Form(/* ... */);
        });
  }
```

```
  Future<List<Match_detail>> Grille_display() async {
    // ...

    return EquipeList.fromJson(response.body);
  }
```

Convert a JSON string into a list.

```
class EquipeList {
  // ...

  factory EquipeList.fromJson(String jsonArrayString) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonMapList =
        json.decode(jsonArrayString).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    List<Match_detail> result = jsonMapList
        .map((json) => Match_detail.fromJson(json))
        .cast<Match_detail>()
        .toList();

    return EquipeList(breed: result);
  }
}
```

> Please see [Effective Dart: Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style), if we use a consistent style across the entire Dart ecosystem, it makes it easier for all of us to learn from and contribute to each others’ code.

Comment: i have tested and i have now a lot errors, Nothing works :(

Comment: Please update your code and explain your new issue.